# What's the good practice to pass data from a header component

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Inside my **stackNavigator** I've made a custom component named **SearchBarHeader** which is located inside the header

Inside the **SearchBarHeader** component there's a **state** which is **what's the user is searching**

I need that state to update my **FlatList** component inside my **Search** component

My question is what should I go for redux ? Passes data through navigationOption ? Something else ?

```
const SearchStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Search: {
      screen: Search,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: <SearchBarHeader navigation={navigation} />
      })
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Search"
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use redux, with redux you can store all your application state in a single object accessible to all your components. If you use navigationOption to pass your data it will be more difficult to maintain your application when the your app logic grow

Answer (score 0):

Redux is good for state management and passing data between components, but it has a pretty big learning curve.

But in parent child datapassing you can simply use props.

in parent,

`this.props.navigation.navigate('ChildComponent', {my_data: 'this is the sample data string'})`

in child,

`this.props.navigation.state.params.my_data`

This is the easiest way.

Apart from that you can use React context API which is very easy to learn and implement. 
You can refer the documentation here. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html